# Splitting multiple elements and sending via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to map every element that has a contenteditable attribute in order to send the results with each individual element's value being sent. However, I am running into a problem when I try to use comma's inside a field because I am joining the elements then splitting them to get an array of values.

Here is my code:

```
function getProfileData(element, button) {
    var profile_data = $(element).html();

    var data = $(element).blur(function() {
        profile_data = $(element).map(function() {
            return this.innerHTML;
        }).get();

    });

    $(button).on('click', function() {
        var edited_content = profile_data.join(", ");

        var split = edited_content.split(",");

        $.ajax({
            method : "POST",
            url : "/members/profile/create-profile",
            data : {
                display_name : split[0],
                email_address : split[1],
                age : split[2],
                location : split[3],
                bio : split[4]
            },
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Profile saved!");
            location.href = '/members/profile';
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("Error saving profile, please try again");
        });
    });
}
```

Is there any way to not having a comma inside a field cut off the rest of the text after it?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `profile_data` already an array if you can use `.join()`? I'm not sure what joining and splitting it again is supposed to be doing.

Comment: well, my main issue is that splitting it with a comma messes up the text field if I put a comma in it.

Comment: Yeah I can see how that would be an issue. I'm just curious as to why you are joining and splitting `profile_data`. Can't you just use it as is like `display_name: profile_data[0],`?

Comment: yeah, you are exactly right. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)